# Get value of child node with row index

Tags: javascript

How to get the value of child node using rowindex, which is dynamically created?

I tried with the below code, but the error appears `"Unable to get the value of the property childnodeID"`

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var Row = table.rows['childnodeID']; //error
Row.cells[0].innerText = i;
```

Comment: `'childnodeID'` shouldn't be a string; it should be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childnodeID` must be a number.Index never be a string.It must be a number

Comment: The 'childnodeID' is the id of the child node which is dynamically created.

Comment: then find the index of that child then use it

Comment: `var Row1 = table.rows[5];` got error - unable to get the value of 5, while using table.rows, but i used table.childNode, the error appears in the next line `Row.cells[0].innerText = i;` as cells value is undefined.